# How to make Gradle compile Groovy tests before Java tests

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

The Groovy plugin for Gradle claims that it `"supports joint compilation, which allows to freely mix and match Groovy and Java code, with dependencies in both directions"`.

However, I don't think this applies to test code.

I have a Java 'sample' test in `src/test/java...` which uses a class which is located in `src/test/groovy`.

When trying to build with Gradle, I get an error like this:

```
SwingJavaFXSampleAppTestInJava.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
SwingJavaFXSampleAppTest swingJavaFx = new SwingJavaFXSampleAppTest();
```

Notice that `SwingJavaFXSampleAppTest` is a Groovy class that has not been compiled yet (in the Gradle output I can see that it did not run the `compileTestGroovy` before it tried `compileTestJava` because the former depends on the latter).

I am able to build this same project with Maven using the groovy-eclipse plugin.

Why does it not work in Gradle when it claims to support compilation in any order, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Do you mean `src/test/groovy` instead of `src/groovy/java`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), only code passed to `GroovyCompile` tasks is joint-compiled. So either you put both Java and Groovy code into `src/main/groovy`, or you reconfigure the source sets:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/groovy"]
```

For tests, replace all occurrences of `main` with `test`.

Comment: Using the above instructions for test dirs actually caused lots of tests to start failing, but it indeed fixed the compilation issue. What kind of side-effect can cause seemingly all of my tests that use inheritance (some tests are common to many classes) to just break with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`???

Comment: With such little information, t's impossible to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to move your java tests into `src/test/groovy`.