# Unable to find main class :bootRepackage

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle, spring-boot

I got a problem with my gradle build. I use the standard proposed by the Spring Website (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), but when I try to use gradle build, I got this error :

[image: My gradle problem]

It doesnt work for this gradle, but when I use another one (that I took when I was at school) it work perfectly.

Comment: Do you actually have a main method (in the guide it's in the `Application`class)?

Comment: I have one in /main/java/hello/Application.class :package main.java.hello;

public class Application {

 public static void main() {
  System.out.println("Test");
 }
}

Comment: Is that "/main/java" or "./src/main/java"? Maybe you could put your code on github or something?

Comment: Doesn't a `main()` method need `String[] args`?

Comment: Was that, thanks for all :-)

Answer (score 33):

There are two possibilities

1. Your source directory is not in the right location (use the sourceSets directive to fix this. your source directory should resemble something like `src/main/java/your/package`)
2. Add this to indicate where your main class is

   ```
   springBoot {
        mainClass = "hello.FileUploader"
   }
   ```

I am pretty sure it is 1.

Comment: For me, it was 2. :) Once I decided to plug in Spring Boot, I didn't realise I needed to config the main class. Still getting my way around both Gradle and Spring Boot...

Comment: For me it was number 1: I didn't have `java` in my path -- I had `src/main/my/package` instead of `src/main/java/my/package`

Comment: I'm joint compiling Java and Groovy with `build.gradle` configured like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164339/185034, in other words I moved the `sourceSets`. #2 worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

I also have this problem, Here I solved the problem:

use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter` instead of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`, if your project is only an module that will be used in other project.

Or Set the main class in gradle:

```
mainClassName = 'your.package.MainClass'
```

Or Just disable the `bootRepackage`

```
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}
```

Comment: I just disabled repackage because it is just  shared project in my case

Answer (score 7):

There is no main method in your project (otherwise the plugin would find one). A main method has a very specific signature, so check that you have `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: This is not true, I am having the same problem and there is a public static void main(String[] args) in my project.

Answer (score 6):

If the main class is not defined in the current project which the build.gradle file belongs to, but you want to launch it for some purpose, like sprint integration test. Do it like this:

Adding

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'your.app.package.Application'
}
```

in build.gradle (after the line apply plugin: 'spring-boot', because the plugin needs to be loaded) fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old post. But I came across this issue while trying to build my first spring- boot application (https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch).
So the location of the pom.xml, mentioned in the tutorial is incorrect. You need to place it outside your src folder.
So here is the final directory structure - 
    /workspace/src/main/java/hello/HelloController.java
    /workspace/src/main/java/hello/Application.java
    /workspace/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by specifying the encoding. Probably it's because I wrote the code in an IDE.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar build <filename>.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well.

I was confused by the location of `build.gradle` file: I thought it should be located in **src/main/java/hello**, because it is mentioned right after the instruction to create this sub-directory structure.

It should be placed in the *root folder containing **src** folder*. Once I did that and called "`gradle build`" from the root folder and not "`./gradlew build`" as the guide instructs, build was successful.

I did not perform the standard installation for gradle, just downloaded the binaries, maybe this is the reason that "`./gradlew build`" failed for me.