# Gradle 4.7 build throw error executing task bootRepackage

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

While executing `gradle build` command in my existing **spring boot project** which was / is building fine with older version of Gradle (For ex: 3.4.*).

But after I upgraded Gradle to latest version **(4.7)** using SDK, its started throw error while building.

**Config List:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
```

**Spring Boot Details:**

```
springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
```

**build.gradle** *Note: I can't publish whole build file. So giving some import lines to analyse.*

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:${springBootVersion}"
}
}

subprojects {
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

// make sure bootRepackage is included in task graph
project.tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith("artifactory") } .each { it.dependsOn assemble }

// so we can maintain both "normal" and "boot" jars
springBoot {
    classifier = 'boot' 
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            // from components.java

            // "boot" jar
            artifact ("$buildDir/libs/${project.name}-${version}-boot.war") { 
                classifier = 'boot' 
            }
        }
    }
}

def profiles = 'development'

bootRun {
    args = [
        "--spring.profiles.active=" + profiles
    ]
}

defaultTasks 'bootRun'

// Other tasks and dependency list 
 }
```

**Output from Command Line:**

> gradle build

```
Task :test-service:bootRepackage FAILED 

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test-service:bootRepackage'.
> Unable to find main class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: And the error is.... ?

Comment: @ToYonos Just now updated.. Sorry

Comment: Do all of your subprojects contain a Spring Boot application (typically a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and a main method)? If they do not, then you should only apply the Spring Boot plugin to the project that does.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes all sub projects contains seperate Main class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5.x [only supports Gradle 2 (2.9 or later) and Gradle 3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-gradle-installation). Gradle 4 is not supported.

You could either stick with Gradle 3.x or upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0.x which does support Gradle 4.

Comment: I didnt think in this way. There is no backward compatibility!! Let me switch my gradle to lower version and try.

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly states that -

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test-service:bootRepackage'.
> Unable to find main class
```

Please check if you have entry similar in your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.my.MyApplication' // your application main class goes here
```

Comment: I have seen this solution but I cannot apply this now, because I have 3 diff sub-projects under api. my point, why its not working now after I upgrade my Gradle to 4.7

Comment: Try spring boot 2.0 release and check the same ? Spring boot 2.0 gradle plugin was designed for gradle 4.0 or later. Eitherways, you can mention mainclass for spring boot to run. try to mention under bootRepackage task.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22528114/2003986), you have to set the main class :

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'your.app.MainClass' 
}
```

Comment: I have 3 diff sub projects under api so cannot do this change. And i dont want to do this in build.gradle because its working fine with lower gradle version.