# Gradle: get a Groovy test script to use an auxiliary Java class

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, import

I'm trying to work out how I get a Groovy test script to import a Java class during the testing phase ...

Specifically I want to use `JavaFXThreadingRule`: .java file from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18988752/595305) (or rather [here](http://andrewtill.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/junit-rule-for-javafx-controller-testing.html) and so included in my Java test source path) and then `import` it in my Groovy test script to use as an annotation.

The Groovy test script path is src\test\ft\groovy\core\testscript.groovy.
The .java file is src\test\ft\java\core\JavaFXThreadingRule.java.
The package line I've used in both is "package core;"
My "sourceSets" clause in build.gradle looks like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/ft/java' ]
        }
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/ft/groovy', 'src/test/ut/groovy']
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly the build.gradle output shows that the `compileTestJava` task is run before the `compileTestGroovy` task ... and yet I get

> unable to resolve class core.JavaFXThreadingRule  @ line 18, column 1.
>   import core.JavaFXThreadingRule    ^

NB I also tried "import JavaFXThreadingRule" - same result.

In addition to just wanting to resolve the problem I'm also wondering how Gradle decides what order to do the tasks `compileTestJava` and `compileTestGroovy`... and whether I shouldn't perhaps make my `compileTestGroovy` explicitly dependent on `compileTestJava`...

Comment: Stick the Java file under your Groovy path

Comment: @Ori Dar that class file (and 3 others it produces) are actually under build\classes\java\test (this is a Windoze machine).

Comment: @tim_yates... Ha... thanks, works.  I tried that initially, but I think I made the mistake of not including the package statement.  Now I put it in it works.  Still seems slightly puzzling that the compileTestGroovy task can't pick up and use classes from the compileTestJava task.  Sigh: I have much to learn about Gradle.

Comment: Think this is a groovy compiler thing, not necessarily a gradle thing. Glad it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Yates I found the "workaround" of putting this Java file in with the Groovy ones... but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164339/595305) gave me another clue, and I then changed my build.gradle to be like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/ft/groovy', 'src/test/ut/groovy', 'src/test/ft/java' ]
        }
    }
}
```

... works ... no doubt obvious to old Gradle hands.

That question and answer referenced above were talking about the app code classes (and Gradle tasks). Unless some Gradle expert can say otherwise I'm assuming that the Groovy test compile task and Java test compile task are completely separate and can't "see" one another's classes...